# Step words anagram python

Tags: python

A step word is formed by taking a given word, adding a letter, and anagramming the result. For example, starting with the word "APPLE", you can add an "A" and anagram to get "APPEAL".

Given a global dictionary of words, create a function step(word) that returns a list of all unique, valid step words appearing in the dictionary.

Dictionary: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eneko/data-repository/master/data/words.txt

I made a dictionary using the link using:

```
>>> words = open('words.txt', encoding='ascii').read().upper().split()
```

This assignment should be completed without any other library function calls. There are several solutions, but some are better and faster than others. How can you speed up your solution?

The solution should look like this.

```
>>> step("APPLE")

>>>['APPEAL', 'CAPPLE', 'PALPED', 'LAPPED', 'DAPPLE', 'ALEPPO', 'LAPPER', 'RAPPEL', 'LAPPET', 'PAPULE', 'UPLEAP']
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? That should be included so we don't waste our time repeating the same mistakes you have already determined to be inadequate.

Comment: "This assignment should be completed without any other library function calls. There are several solutions, but some are better and faster than others. How can you speed up your solution?" sounds like homework.

Comment: Dear@Lifeiscomplex, this is an old question that I'm not sure what is the `nature` of it? But for me just for pure intellectual curiosity and `learning` purpose.  Hope it's helpful. I'm putting my points to attract attention here
... Hopfully this site will not become bullying to new learner's like me.  Thanks for the feedback and support.

Comment: @annie2020 thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @python_user Thanks, I got it already.

Answer (score 4):

As we know anagrams in sorted form are exactly same.

Logic:

1. Create a dictionary for look-up. where key would be sorted string and value would be array of anagrams of the key.
2. Add all the alphabet (A..Z) one by one to the input string, one at a time such that the result string contains one extra alphabet than the input string and is in sorted form. Now, find the anagrams in the dictionary created in previous step.
3. Combination of all the values you got from step 2 will be your expected output.

Talking about the complexity of run-time code. (excluding the time to create constants like dictionary for look-up, alphabets)

It will take O(NxLogN) + O(26xN) ~ O(NxLogN)

- 26: Number of Alphabets
- N: length of input string

1. To **sort the input string once** the `sorted` function will take `NlogN` time in worst case.
2. To **create the new sorted string** by addition of one alphabet to the sorted input string will take `26xN` time.

Code:

```
# array of all valid and unique words from the dictionary
valid_words = set(open('words.txt', encoding='ascii').read().upper().split())

look_up = {}
for word in valid_words:
  try:
    look_up[''.join(sorted(word))].append(word)
  except KeyError:
    look_up[''.join(sorted(word))] = [word]

alphabet_array = []
alphabet_dict = {}
for i in range (65, 91):
  alphabet_dict[chr(i)]=i
  alphabet_array.append(chr(i))

def step(word):
  sorted_string = sorted(word)
  length_of_input_string = len(sorted_string)
  output_values = []
  for i in alphabet_array:
    new_str = ''
    value_added = 0
    for j in range (0, length_of_input_string):
      if value_added==0 and (alphabet_dict[sorted_string[j]] > alphabet_dict[i]):
        new_str += i
        value_added = 1
      new_str += sorted_string[j]
    if value_added==0:
      new_str += i
    try:
      output_values+=look_up[new_str]
    except KeyError:
      pass
  return output_values

if __name__ == '__main__':
  input_string = 'APPLE'
  print (step(input_string))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since anagrams have the same letters, if you alphabetically sort the letters in a word, you would get the same string for words that are anagrams of each other.
For example:
LEAP -> alphabetically sorted -> AEPL
PALE -> alphabetically sorted -> AEPL

1) You should iterate through all the words in your dictionary and create a look up of the alphabetically sorted string key to a list of words that have the same key.

Given a list of words

```
["PALE","LEAP"]
```

you will get the anagram lookup as follows

```
{
"AEPL"=>["PALE","LEAP"],
...
}
```

2) Next, take the input word, and try different combinations of alphabets to create a new string. Sort this string and lookup against the anagram dictionary for matches. Concatenate the lists returned into one list and return that list.

Let's say the input word is PEA, generate all combinations

```
["PEAA","PEAB"...,"PEAL",...]
```

Alphabetically sort every candidate word

```
["AAEP","ABEP",...,"AEPL",...]
```

Then lookup and concatenate the lists returned

```
["LEAP","PALE"]
```

Let me know if you want the python code here as well, but it should be easy to code this up. The speedup is primarily due to preprocessing the anagram lookup dictionary, due to which the final lookup runs in near constant time, but it uses additional space of the order of the words in the input list.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the implementation and explanations following:
For this problem we can divide it into two parts: firstly try to build up a
words map using `defaultdict` to store all similar anagram words into list.  For example words that have same letters, such as TEA, EAT, should have the same key.

Creating the word maps will enable us to loop through N words and sort them.
The run time will be O(N * k logk) - assuming the average word length is k.

Secondly, we can loop through each letter and add it to the given word, and
check if the new value are already for this key is in the maps. If so, we
find the step word and add it to the results.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_uppercase as uppers

def make_wordmap(dictionary):   # first part - build up the lookup hash map

    maps = defaultdict(list)

    for word in dictionary:
        maps[tuple(sorted(word))].append(word)
    return maps

def step_words(word, dc):              # search the word from dict by using the maps
    word_map =  make_wordmap(dc)

    step_words = []

    for letter in uppers:
        key = tuple(sorted(word + letter))
        if word_map[key]:
            step_words.extend(word_map[key])

    return step_words


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dictionary = ['APPEAL', 'TEA', 'DAVY']
    word = 'APPLE'
    print(step_words(word, dictionary))
    print(step_words('DAY', dictionary))
```

Comment: ... _should be completed without any other library function calls_

Comment: To learn a language is to learn to use the best available features - including standard lib.

Comment: And people refers these lib. as `batteries`.  Of course, you can reinvent the wheels - but the performance will not be optimal...

Answer (score 0):

To easily check if a word is an anagram of another we sort both words first.
And check if, after sorting they are equals. As anagram is just the rearranging of characters.
To check if in a word we can add some char to create another word, we just check if the char of a word are present in the other word.

```
list_of_words = ['handsome', 'handy', 'notright', 'and']
word_to_check = 'adn'

anagram_can_add_chars= []
anagram_cannot_add_chars= []

# loop through the list of words
for word in list_of_words:

  # we sort the string so that we know that we have all the chars
  if sorted(word_to_check) == sorted(word):
    anagram_cannot_add_chars.append(word)

  # we convert the strings to set
  # this will remove duplicate chars on each
  # but we can always add them 
  if set(sorted(word_to_check)).issubset(set(sorted(word))):
    anagram_can_add_chars.append(word)

print(anagram_can_add_chars)
print('---')
print(anagram_cannot_add_chars)
```

result :

```
['handsome', 'handy', 'and']
---
['and']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple piece of code which: read the file and build a lookup table.
There are some code to handle special cases found in the file.

```
## letters which will be added to the word to lookup for anagrams
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'


## read the file, lowercase the letters, and split it in case you have some blanks
dictionary = open('words.txt', encoding='ascii').read().lower().split()


## build a lookup dict which holds all words for a given sorted set of letters
lookup = {}
for word in dictionary:
    try:
        if word not in lookup[''.join(sorted(word))]:   ## avoid possible duplicates in the dictionary if word is already in the dictionnary, like anagrams, or Upper/lowercase
            lookup[''.join(sorted(word))].append(word)
    except:
        lookup[''.join(sorted(word))] = [word] ## create new dictionnary entry if key does not exists


## step function to find anagrams with one more letter
def step(word):
    word = word.lower() ## works with lowercase word only
    output = []
    for i in alphabet: ## try to find anagrams with one extra letter added to the word
        try:
            output += lookup[''.join(sorted(word+i))] ## add the word found if an anagram is found in lookup dict
        except:
            pass
    return list(set(output)) ## be sure to return only unique answers in a list


## main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (step('aPPle'))
    print (step('OV'))      ## test for the dupes 'Ova' and 'ova' found in the file
    print (step('a'))       ## test for the one letter dupes 'a' and 'A' found in the file
    print (step('A'))       ## test for the one letter dupes 'a' and 'A' found in the file
```

Answer (score 0):

The below program will Search for the Multiple Combinations of the input string and print the Anagrams. This can be further finetuned, but this is a basic starting point for checking the valid Anagram values.

```
#Program: Anagram Finder

from itertools import permutations

#Store the words text file in to an object for searching

with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    dictionary = f.read()
    dictionary = [x.lower() for x in dictionary.split('\n')]

#Get permutations of input word
def get_perms(value, length):
    for l in range(length):
        for perm in permutations(value, l):
            yield ''.join(perm)
    else:
        return []

# Search the dictionary for possible Anagrams and list the valid ones
def fncSearchForAnagram():

  y = ["Apple"] # Anagram check Sample input.
  for i in y:
      perms = get_perms(i, len(i))
      for item in perms:
          if item.lower() in dictionary:  # converting search string to lower since the word file has all lower case chars
              # This output will be your Anagram combination word listed in the Words.txt File
              print(item)


fncSearchForAnagram()
```